# How can I open a ps1 script in Powershell ISE from the command line?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to figure out how I can open a ps1 script (or any file) in PS ISE by using the $psISE object.

How can I open a document tab in PS ISE from the command line in PS ISE itself (without using File > Open)?

Comment: It's worth noting that in Windows 2008 R2 the PowerShell ISE is an OS Feature that needs to be installed through Server Manager, it isn't installed by default. It **is** installed by default in Windows Server 2012, but since I didn't find this information in other related threads I think it is worth mentioning here.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

psEdit filename

Answer (score 11):

PowerShell 2.0 in Windows 7, PSEdit does not work.
Use "ise", which is an alias for `powershell_ise.exe`.

```
ex. ise .\myscript.ps1
```

Comment: +1 When working in the standard PS console, this is the way to open a file in the ISE.

Comment: What is ex. Here?

Answer (score 8):

New tab:
$tab = $psISE.PowerShellTabs.Add()

Load script file to new tab:
$tab.Files.Add("full_path_to_script_file.ps1")

Answer (score 5):

Programmatically, this works:

```
$psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.Files.Add("$pwd\foo.ps1")
```

Which is essentially what the PSEdit function uses.  To see this execute:

```
Get-Command PSEdit | Format-List *
```

Answer (score 5):

I took the psedit command and allowed input from the pipeline

```
Function psedit {
param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]$filenames)
foreach ($filename in $filenames)
    {
        dir $filename | where {!$_.PSIsContainer} | %{
            $psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.Files.Add($_.FullName) > $null
        }
 }     
 }
```

This allows me to something like this

```
7 >  ls test*.ps1 | psedit
```

I find this useful when working on modules and I have several scripts in a directory

Andy